# Is my understanding of the $u$ substitution process correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

I'm just getting a hang of doing integrals, so I was wondering if my understanding of the $u$ substitution process is correct. If we have

$$\int f(x) \ dx$$

we write $f(x) = g'(x) \cdot h(x) = g'(x) \cdot h(g^{-1}(g(x)))$ where $g$ is an injective differentiable real function so that

$$\int f(x) \ dx = \int g'(x) \cdot h(g^{-1}(g(x))) \ dx = M(g(x)) + C  $$

where $M$ is a primitive of $h \circ g^{-1}$. We conveniently express $g(x)$ with the variable $u$ and define $du=g'(x) \cdot dx$.

Is this fundamentally the idea, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier.

You write $f(x)=g'(x) \cdot h(g(x))$. If you are able to find a primitive of $h$, say $H$, then it is evident (using the chain rule) that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} H(g(x)) = h(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) = f(x)$$
or equivalently,
$$\int f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \int h(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = H(g(x)) +C$$

So that, symbolically, you call $u= g(x)$ and $\mathrm{d} u = g'(x) \mathrm{d} x$, and solve the integral $\int h(u) \, \mathrm{d} u$.

Comment: Fair enough but I brought up the inverse because we sometimes have to make back substitutions.